# Call a function from a class in python?

Tags: python, pandas, class

Newbie to python here.Need help on using classes in python
I have two functions

```
def df1():
  raw_data = {'preTestScore': [4, 24, '', 2, 3],'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
return df1
```

df1

```
        preTestScore    postTestScore
      0      4                  25
      1     24                  94
      2                         57
      3      2                  62
      4      3                  70
```

Similarly another df

```
def df2():
  raw_data = {'preTestScore': [14, 4, 15, 12, 13],'postTestScore': ['', 4, 7, 2, 7]}
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
return df2
```

df2

```
        preTestScore    postTestScore
      0     14                  
      1      4                  4
      2     15                  7
      3     12                  2
      4     13                  7
```

I want define a class and call two func and work on from that

```
   class MyClass:
         #call df1
         #call df2
         #work from that
         df1 = df1.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
         df2 = df2.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Is there a better way to do it or Should i declare my two funcs as classes?

Comment: `return df1` needs to be indented so it's part of the function. Also, it's not a good idea to use the same name for a variable and the function.

Comment: I think we need more information about what you are trying to accomplish here. @Barmar also raises a good point.

Comment: You need to put parentheses after a function to call it: `x1 = df1().replace(...)`